# How to remove the spaces from top, left & right side of a toolbar?

Tags: android

I'm adding a toolbar in one activity but the toolbar is placed by giving some space from the top left and right. How can I fill the toolbar completely below the status bar?[I have give my output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxPix.png)

Comment: Do you have paddings set on the parent `ViewGroup`? Or margins set on the `Toolbar` itself?

Comment: Post your layout and your code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin if it is set on the toolbar.

ex:-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```